# DataTables inside bootstrap accordion in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables, bootstrap-accordion

I am working on a module where I have to redesign some products. Following is the screenshot of how the products used to get displayed previously.

[image]

Now the products will be displayed inside accordion of their specific name. I am bound to use ui.bootstrap Version: 0.11.0 - 2014-05-01. Following is a sketch of how the products will be displayed now. In each accordion there will be a datatable of that particular product in which the columns will dynamically generate and we would be able to check the particular products we want.

[image]

Following is my html code:

```
                <accordion>
                    <accordion-group ng-repeat="AllProduct in AllProducts">
                        <accordion-heading>
                            {{AllProduct.TypeName}}
                           </accordion-heading>

                    </accordion-group>
                    <table id="dtVoice" class="table manage-user-table offer-mgt-table" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns"></table>
                </accordion>
```

The way i have dynamically created datatables are as follows:

```
 dtColumns.push(DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('').notSortable()
          .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
              return '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showCase.selected[' + data.id + ']"/>';
          }));

        for (var key in $scope.VoiceProducts[0]) {
            if (key == "ProductName" || key == "LongDistanceMinutes" || key == "IsCallWaiting") {
                dtColumns.push(
                  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(key).withTitle(key)

                )
            }

            $scope.dtColumns = dtColumns;
            $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
              .withOption('data', $scope.VoiceProducts)
              .withOption('dataSrc', '')


            angular.element('#dtVoice').attr('datatable', '')
        }
       $compile(angular.element('#dtVoice'))($scope);
```

Following is my json

```
 [
  {
    "ProductList": [
      {
        "ProductName": "Voice",
        "IsActive": false,
        "IsDeleted": false,
        "LongDistanceMinutes": "",
        "IsCallWaiting": "",
        "CallWaitingId": "",
        "IsThreeWayCalling": "",
        "IsCallerId": "",
        "IsCallForwarding": "",
        "IsCallRejection": "",
        "ID": 552,
        "OfferId": 0
      }
    ],
    "ID": 2,
    "IsActive": false,
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "TypeName": "Voice"
  }
]
```

How to put this datatable inside accordion? Because by doing whatever I'm, i'm unable to achieve it.

Comment: And your question is what exactly?

Comment: How to put this datatable inside accordion? Because by doing whatever I'm, i'm unable to achieve it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/manedeepak08/eV37v/1/

Comment: Many thanks but i need to Achieive it with dynamic columns of datatables with bootrap accordion as a boundary.

Comment: check this and explain what needs to be done https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rpbzpX

Comment: I have added new answer that solves your problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**UPDATED: As per new information (using angular-datatable)**

The solution now boils down to computing the columns and options per accordion-group.

[Working Plunker with 2 accordion groups](https://plnkr.co/edit/tm7bAHWARCgNa3jwoWe6?p=preview)

As you can see in the HTML below the options and columns are computed per accordion.

```
<table datatable class="table manage-user-table offer-mgt-table"  dt-options="getDtOptions(AllProduct)" dt-columns="getDtColumns(AllProduct)"></table>
```

Angular code showing getDtColumns and getDtOptions. I have kept the data very simple for demonstration purposes and copied the current `dtColumns` code however you can customize it so that you can even have more than 1 type of table :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'datatables']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, DTColumnBuilder, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder, $timeout, AllProducts) {
  $scope.AllProducts = AllProducts


  $scope.getDtColumns = function(allProduct) {
    var items = allProduct.ProductList;
    if (allProduct.dtColumns) allProduct.dtColumns.length = 0;
    allProduct.dtColumns =  allProduct.dtColumns || [];
    var dtColumns = allProduct.dtColumns;
    dtColumns.push(DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('').withTitle('').notSortable()
      .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showCase.selected[' + full.id + ']"/>';
      }));


    for (var key in items[0]) {
      if (key == "ProductName" || key == "LongDistanceMinutes" || key == "IsCallWaiting") {
        dtColumns.push(
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(key).withTitle(key).notSortable()
        )
      }
    }

    return dtColumns;
  };

  $scope.getDtOptions = function(allProduct) {
    if (allProduct.options) return allProduct.options;
    var items = allProduct.ProductList;
    allProduct.options = allProduct.options || DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('aaData', items);
    return allProduct.options;     
  };


});
```

**OLDER ANSWER without angular-datatable**

First of all I do not recommend jQuery DataTable or any other jQuery component in AngularJS applications. I personally try not to bundle jQuery or perform DOM manipulation using jQuery.

However to get you going with what you have I suggest the following:-

Remove these two lines because simply adding those attributes `datatable` dynamically is not going to trigger the DataTable binding:-

> ```
> angular.element('#dtVoice').attr('datatable', '')
>         }
>        $compile(angular.element('#dtVoice'))($scope);
> ```

and try using something like this:-

$('#dtVoice').DataTable( {columnDefs: $scope.dtColumns });

Further more just to clean up a bit I create a new directive (just typing out loud):

```
app.directive('myDatatable`, function(){
return {
   restrict: 'A',
   scope: {
       'dtColumns': '='
   }
   link: function($scope, elem, attr) {
        $('#dtVoice').DataTable( {columnDefs: $scope.dtColumns});    
   } 
};
});
```

and your table something like below:

```
<table id="dtVoice" 
    class="table manage-user-table offer-mgt-table" 
      dt-options="dtOptions" 
      dt-columns="dtColumns" my-datatable></table>
```

Comment: Does not help. Still not rendering

Comment: Are you using angular-datatable ?

Comment: Ok that explains the down vote  - I will update my answer then. Can you tell me what version of angular-datatable you are using ?

Comment: angular-datatables - v0.6.2

Comment: @Sana check now

Comment: Can you tell me how to get atleast one radio checked of each accordion table. currently im able to only select one from all. Also how to track ID of each tables selected row on save .https://plnkr.co/edit/2Cndr462ChLLfurf2seR?p=preview

Comment: Try this https://plnkr.co/edit/JduhBW5XW3zZDLSHCMhD?p=preview checkout how is injected `parentId`

Comment: one last thing can you please tell me how can i add paging at bottom with this type of implementation

Comment: Each datatable already has paging enabled by default as it can be seen in plnkr.co/edit/JduhBW5XW3zZDLSHCMhD?p=preview Are you able to see paging ?

Comment: I dont want paging on top. I want it on the bottom of the grid

Comment: Show 10 entries etc is shown on top. I want to show it on end

Comment: got it done by .withOption('dom','<"top"f>t<"bottom"<"col-md-3"i><"col-md-4"l>p>')

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on the pass.
Please use ng-if as a flag to recreate the table when the accordion item is active. The accordion and tab components avoid the table to be shown.

The code below can help.Notice the ng-click and ng-if

```
<accordion>
                <accordion-group ng-repeat="AllProduct in AllProducts">
                    <accordion-heading ng-click="setGroup('AllProduct.TypeName')">
                        {{AllProduct.TypeName}}
                       </accordion-heading>

                       <table id="dtVoice" ng-if="group=='AllProduct.TypeName'" class="table manage-user-table offer-mgt-table" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns"></table>

                </accordion-group>

            </accordion>
```

Comment: Have you been able to add check boxes to the first column of datatable and checked the row by Id?