# How to get the radiobutton selected when the accordion get open in datatables

Tags: angularjs, datatables, bootstrap-accordion

With reference to the question here

[DataTable accordions in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322954/datatables-inside-bootstrap-accordion-in-angularjs/48445490#48445490)

When I close the accordion and re-open it, the selected radiobutton is not selected anymore. Following is how I'm trying to do it. I have applied ng-click to accordion header and attached a function to it. Following is my function

```
$scope.selectProduct =function(productTypeName)
{
    if ($scope.selectedProducts[0][productTypeName].length != 0) {
        var table=  $('#dt'+ productTypeName).DataTable();
        for (var row = 0; row < table.context[0].aoData.length; row++)
        {
            if (table.context[0].aoData[row]._aData.ID == $scope.selectedProducts[0][productTypeName]) {
                table.context[0].aoData[row].anCells[0].children[0].Voice.checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code works well but the radiobutton ain't selected.

Following is how I have created radio button:

```
dtVidColumns.push(DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('').notSortable()
    .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<input type="radio" name ="Video"  onclick="angular.element(this).scope().productChange('+data.ID+',name)" />';
}));
```